# Asp.NET Core adds a Plus into the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why does ASP.NET Core add a Plus (+) into the URI, when I try to submit a form using the `get` method?

For example I have two fields to calculate the [BMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index): `height` and `weight`. After submitting the form, I get the following URL:
`http://localhost:59953/?height=170&weight+=65`

In the controller, I only get the `height` parameter because after the weight in the URL, there is a `+`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int height, int weight)
{
    // The height is 170 but the weight is 0!
    return View();
}
```

This is the form Razor code:

```
<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="height">Height in cm</label>
        <input name="height" id="height" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="weight">Weight in kg</label>
        <input name="weight "id="weight" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Calculate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Spaces in the query part of a URL get encoded to a plus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space within the `name` attribute for your weight property, consider removing it:

```
<input name="weight" id="weight" class="form-control"/>
```

By default, spaces are going to be encoded as '+' characters within the URL and since "weight+" isn't the same as "weight", ASP.NET isn't going to be able to properly bind the value.

Additionally, you *may* want to consider using a POST as opposed to a GET request, since you are actually submitting data to the server as opposed to retrieving it, but your use case may vary.

Comment: Hi. What a fail. I was using GET because there I could see where the problem was. I thought, maybe it was a convention to only take the first argument :) Thank you!